# Dar tamaño a nodos concretos con Bokeh en Python

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

Estoy trabajando con un conjunto de datos de tweets de Twitter, y he conseguido pintar los nodos con un mayor numero de Retweets (Rojo el que más tiene, amarillo los que tienen bastantes y verde los que menos tienen) y hasta ahí bien, sin embargo ahora lo que quiero es que tanto los nodos rojos como los naranjas sean de un tamaño mayor que el resto para poder identificarlos facilmente, pero he probado de mil formas y no lo consigo. Aqui dejo el codigo de la parte que me da problemas:

```
    from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
    from bokeh.models import HoverTool, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, from_networkx
    from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
    from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper

    # Cargar el archivo GEXF
    G = nx.read_gexf(gexf_file_path)
    # Prepara el gráfico de Bokeh
    plot = figure(title='Grafo interactivo', tools=[HoverTool(tooltips='@data{safe}'), BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool(), "wheel_zoom"], plot_width=800, plot_height=800)
    pos = nx.random_layout(G)
        
    # Convierte el grafo NetworkX a un objeto Bokeh
    graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, pos)
    
    # Calcular el valor medio de retweet_count
    retweet_count_values=[]
    for node in G.nodes().values():
        if 'retweet_count' in node:
            retweet_count_values.append(node['retweet_count'])
        else:
            retweet_count_values.append(0)
    retweet_count_mean = sum(retweet_count_values) / len(retweet_count_values)
    node_sizes=[]
    for node in G.nodes().values():
        if 'retweet_count' in node and node['retweet_count']>2*retweet_count_mean:
            node_sizes.append(20)
        elif 'retweet_count' in node and node['retweet_count']<2*retweet_count_mean:
            node_sizes.append(10)
        else:
            node_sizes.append(10)
    
    # Configurar el color mapper para asignar colores en función del valor de retweet_count
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=['green', 'orange', 'red'], low=min(retweet_count_values), high=max(retweet_count_values))
    # Pintar los nodos según el valor de retweet_count
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph.update(fill_color={'field': 'retweet_count', 'transform': color_mapper})

    # Asignar la lista de tamaños de nodo al atributo 'size' del GlyphRenderer
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph.size = {'field': 'retweet_count', 'transform': 10}
        
    # Configura las etiquetas de los nodos y los datos del nodo para mostrar en el tooltip
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data['data'] = [', '.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in node_data.items()) for node_data in G.nodes().values()]
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph.size = 10 #AQUI DEBERIA IR node_sizes pero me da error de que solo vale un numero entero para todos los nodos, no uno para cada nodo por separado, asi que no se como hacerlo

    plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

    # Ajusta el rango del gráfico manualmente
    x_values = [pos[node][0] for node in G.nodes()]
    y_values = [pos[node][1] for node in G.nodes()]
    x_range = min(x_values), max(x_values)
    y_range = min(y_values), max(y_values)
    plot.x_range.range_padding = 1.3  # Espacio adicional alrededor del rango
    plot.y_range.range_padding = 1.3  # Espacio adicional alrededor del rango
    plot.x_range.start, plot.x_range.end = x_range
    plot.y_range.start, plot.y_range.end = y_range
    # Muestra el gráfico interactivo
    output_notebook()
    show(plot)
```

Adjunto foto del resultado actual. Como se puede ver en la imagen, los nodos importantes se pintan de otro color, el resto de verde y si pasas el cursor por encima de un nodo se muestran sus datos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]